# creating OData like services using RESTlet

Tags: odata, restlet

I am trying to build a OData interface for Java application.

From what I have seen, one can create fully compliant OData services using microsoft technologies (aka visual studio) using their WCF services. Am I of the right impression?

I am trying to simulate OData services (it is also RESTful) using RESTlet + ROME(for atom feeds) + ROME Propono (for atompub service document). OData specification says that I canm access individual objects of a collection like http://mysite/service.svc/products(1)

Is there a way to represent this in RESTlet?

router.attach("products(id)") will not work
router.attach("products/get/{id}") is not really OData like.

Do you have any suggestions? Am I even doing it right?

Regards,
D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this URI template?

router.attach("products({id})")